# Automatic rejection of edit where I only added tags

Tags: support, editing

To my surprise, I tried to add a couple of tags to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/483200/is-the-weight-of-a-bicycle-frame-significant-compared-to-the-body-weight) but the edit was automatically rejected with an error message about how the changes must be at least 6 characters long, pointing to the body of the question. Is this a thing now or did I do womething wrong?

**Edit:** I tried to add a screenshot in the present question and guess what? It was rejected with the message "body is missing"...

Comment: Try again? You should be able to make a tag-only edit regardless of your reputation.

Comment: @Chris just tried once more and the same thing happened. (I've done the same kind of edit succesfully several times before.) Also, please take a look at the edit in the present question.

Comment: Did you leave an edit summary? I can't remember if that's required, but it's worth a try. Otherwise, it sounds like a bug, and you should ask about it on the mother meta, after reading the suggestions [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267494/380389).

Comment: (Partially)Replicated on Chrome. I wasn't able to suggest an edit with the question you mentioned, but was able to (suggest an) edit with [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/483364/why-is-it-that-a-force-that-acts-on-two-masses-can-cause-both-masses-to-accelera) question. Weird.

Comment: (Continued)..... In the revision history, you'll see that I have edited more than just tags, but actually I had first suggested the edit with just changed tags, but modified it before the OP approved.

Comment: @Chris yes I left a summary. I tried again just now, because of the possible cache problem that the link mentions, but the exact same thing happened...

Comment: @Helen Make a post on the mother meta about it then. Especially if Eagle has the same problem, it's likely this is a reproducible bug the developers can look into.